# node.js sqlite3 - error when adding rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, transactions, sql-insert

This error occurs when I add 20 strings to my table through a for-loop:

*ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR: cannot start a transaction within a transaction at Error (native)*

Here is the relevant code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var Players_db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/Players');

Players_db.serialize(function() 
{
    Players_db.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
    Players_db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Players(string TEXT)");
    Players_db.run("COMMIT");
    console.log('Players_db init')
});

// This part is a simplification, but it shouldn't make a difference.
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++) 
{
    Players_db.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
    Players_db.run("INSERT INTO Players VALUES('"+a_string+"')");
    Players_db.run("COMMIT");
}
```

It also appears that the for-loop finishes successfully (and data is being appended to the db), but shortly afterwards it crashes with the said error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        Players_db.serialize(function() 
        {
            Players_db.run("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++) 
            {
               Players_db.run("INSERT INTO Players VALUES('"+a_string+"')");
            }
            Players_db.run("COMMIT");
        })
```

Comment: It works, but due to the nature of the application, I cannot add the rows from the same serialize event.

Comment: I figured out I could use a serialize function for every new row. Thank you1